# XSLT to format a XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like below

```
<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
    <column name="VALUE">value1</column>
    <column name="NAME">name1</column>
</row>
<row>
    <column name="VALUE">value2</column>
    <column name="NAME">name2</column>
</row>
<row>
    <column name="VALUE">value3</column>
    <column name="NAME">name3</column>
</row>
</resultset>
```

i want to convert this xml into below structure using xslt

```
<Property name="name1" value="value1"/>
<Property name="name2" value="value2"/>
<Property name="name3" value="value3"/>
```

Comment: This is a rather trivial task - where exactly are stuck with it?  Note that the result you show is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document (no single root element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a single template rule

```
<xsl:template match="row">
  <Property name="{column[@name='NAME']}" value="{column[@name='VALUE']}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I want output like this <Properties>
<Property name="name1" value="value1"/>
<Property name="name2" value="value2"/>
<Property name="name3" value="value3"/>
</Properties>

Comment: Which part of that are you finding difficult?